# Cucumber Test: Referring to a Rails Object Created by an Observer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, pickle

I have a cucumber test, which needs to refer to an object that is created by an observer and am wondering if there is a way to do that.

Specifically,

1. There is a Profile instance that is automatically created when a User instance is created.
2. In Cucumber (and using Pickle), I create a User instance:
3. The user_observer automatically creates a profile associated with "u_1"
4. And I want to refer to the Profile in a different scenario.

For example.

```
Given the following users exist:
| user | first_name | last_name |
| test | john       | malkovich |
And the following resume_packs exist:
| profile      | page | pack_name |
| test.profile |  2   | who's who |
```

test.profile is a space filler, so what is the actual way to refer to test.profile?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to use your own step definitions and create the stuff you need yourself.

```
Given the user "John Malkovich" has a resume pack
```